# How can I determine the height and width of a fieldset border?

Tags: javascript, size, fieldset

I have a fieldset and I'd like to determine in JavaScript the height (thickness) of the borders at the top (including the legend) and bottom, also the width of the borders on the left and right.

I'm trying to resize a JavaScript table located in the fieldset so the fieldset + table are sized to fit in a particular area on the page.  If I set the table to the dimensions of the area then the fieldset+table combo is too large for the area, so I need to subtract the space the fieldset border is taking up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0];
alert(getStyle(fieldset, "borderTopWidth"));
alert(getStyle(fieldset, "paddingTop"));

//http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Do I also need to get the height of the legend, or half the legend since the line bisects it?

Comment: @Paul You'll have to play around with it-- by taking into account various styles, e.g. height, borderTopWidth, marginTop, paddingTop, etc., you should be able to get what you want.